# chef-solo bootstrap for ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rvm, chef-infra

In the last week I've been playing around with chef-solo and I have many questions.

I want to use ruby 1.9.2-p290 and Ubuntu 10.04 so it looks like I will have to use something like rvm.

Should I be using RVM with chef-solo?

If I'm using RVM should I install it 'system wide' or 'per user'?

Or should I be using Ubuntu 11.04 server instead and just use the ruby in through apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with a RVM system wide install approach, here is my setup:

https://github.com/map7/chef-solo

Answer (score 0):

I was having some issues with this recently. RVM and chef don't play nice together. See the following links for more info:

http://blog.zottmann.org/post/5873082674/a-few-notes-about-chef-ubuntu-10-04-ruby-1-9-2

http://help.opscode.com/discussions/problems/264-getting-started-with-chef-under-rvm-ruby-192